# Copying HTML file also copies the related files to it stored in _files folder can it be done for other type of files?

Tags: c++, html, winapi, filesystems, file-copying

If we have a HTML file **test.htm** and folder with its related files like (images, style sheets etc.) in folder with name **test_files** or **test.files** then folder get copied/moved automatically as we copy/move html file.

[Mechanism of above operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So my question is, can such thing can be achieved for other types of files too?

I have a XML file and few files related to that which I want to move along with XML file. Will it be possible?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: [Copy hook handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144063.aspx), perhaps?

Comment: I would recommend embedding the data into the XML if business processes allow. What you want is not generally possible (there exist other applications besides Windows Explorer).

Comment: The copying behavior for HTML files built in to the Shell, it does not use a Copy Hook handler. Copy Hook handlers only apply to folders and printer objects, not to files, as evident by the fact that they can only be registered under the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory` registry key.